# SSIS Issue Pulling Data From Snowflake - [CData Snowflake Source] Error: Get data error: Received metadata with an incompatible version number

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to run a simple data flow task in SSIS pulling data from Snowflake to SQL Server using a component from `CDATA` called `Snowflake Source`.

Connection works and I can also see a preview of the data but when actually running the package I get the following error message:

> [CData Snowflake Source [2]] Error: System.Exception: Get data error: Received metadata with an incompatible version number
> at CData.SSIS.Snowflake.SSISSourceComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers, IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)

Has anyone experienced this before or know what to do in order to fix it?

Comment: please add a tag of cdata as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced this error many time , when i use some custom script component or third party component.

Issue : We do remove or delete some component but some of the reference is not removed from package (it is very tough to debug )

Create fresh package it will work .